# Convert a .ui into a .py with pyuic?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I'm using OSX 10.8, python 2.7.5

I just built a GUI with QtDesigner, and I was trying to figure out how to use it with Python. I found I have to use "pyuic" and how to do it here : [pyqt installation problem in mac osx snow leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576629/pyqt-installation-problem-in-mac-osx-snow-leopard), but following the approach given here gave me a pretty nice

```
pyuic: command not found
```

Any advice would be most welcome on how to solve this

Comment: Your problem is PyQt installation on OSX 10.8, solve that and you will have the `pyuic` command. Using homebrew?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about OSX, but another solution is to use the [uic](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#the-uic-module) module of PyQt4 (pyuic4 is just a wrapper around this module). Here is an example of a custom QDialog using a ui file called `mydialog.ui` :

```
import os

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import uic

class myDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
    uic.loadUi(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"mydialog.ui"), self)
```

Note that the `loadUi` method last argument is `self`: this means that you will have access to all widgets as attributes of your class, ie `dialog.textEdit` instead of `dialog.ui.textEdit`.