# Going from pyqt designer to exe file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, py2exe, qt-designer

I just finished the first draft of a .ui file in the designer of pyqt, and I am wondering how I go from the .ui file to an exe to let someone test out my ui... I currently have a makefile that translates my .ui file into a .py file, but now I want to go from .py to .exe

Does anybody know how to do this? I have py2exe downloaded but not sure if this is what I want...

Please assume the people I want to test this don't have python downloaded and are using Windows (cross platform is better but windows will be used)

Thank you!

EDIT: when i run py2exe on my test.py (which was made from the test.ui)

I use 
    py -3.6 -m py2exe.build_exe test.py

and get

```
C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\makeExe>py -3.6 -m py2exe.build_exe test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", lin
e 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", lin
e 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
py2exe\build_exe.py", line 145, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
py2exe\build_exe.py", line 141, in main
    builder.analyze()
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
py2exe\runtime.py", line 160, in analyze
    self.mf.import_hook(modname)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
    module = self._gcd_import(name)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
    return self._find_and_load(name)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
    self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
py2exe\mf3.py", line 388, in _scan_code
    for what, args in self._scan_opcodes(code):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
py2exe\mf3.py", line 417, in _scan_opcodes
    yield "store", (names[oparg],)
IndexError: tuple index out of range

C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\makeExe>
```

Comment: Try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742673/convert-a-ui-into-a-py-with-pyuic) on creating a python file from a .ui file and then build your executable.

Comment: I already have a way to go from .ui to .py (im sorr if that wasnt clear in the question), but im not sure how to go from that .py to .exe, or if I even can without adding any extra code

Comment: Look at [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Deploying_PyQt_Applications) for guidance on deploying your PyQt application.

Comment: try with `pyinstaller` :P

Comment: pyinstaller worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Py2exe didn't support signing whereas Pyinstaller has support for signing from version 1.4

So this is also a solution

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed test.py
```